# Embedding server-based bokeh plot in html

Tags: javascript, python, html, bokeh

I am relatively new to both Bokeh/Python and HTML.  I have created a served-based Bokeh plot which I want to display on a webpage.  I have been following the instructions at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html.  In particular, I am using autoload_server to generate a script.  However, when I place the script tag in the head of the HTML document (which is apparently correct, according to the last line at the above link):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script
src="http://localhost:5006/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=6abffe3c-d0dc-4e7b-80d3-0e7dc2d1b100&bokeh-absolute-url=http://localhost:5006&bokeh-session-id=bTinOCNtjuDagomoQgcw1EKJ7dUMkzSQJIRKozmGiqTc"
id="6abffe3c-d0dc-4e7b-80d3-0e7dc2d1b100"
data-bokeh-model-id="676400d3-9929-4d9e-aefe-2fb440f526d6"
data-bokeh-doc-id=""
></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The following error message appears on the webpage:

Bokeh Error
Error rendering Bokeh model: element with id '6abffe3c-d0dc-4e7b-80d3-0e7dc2d1b100' must be under body

So then I remove the script from the head and place it in the body.  But this results in a completely blank webpage; the plot doesn't render at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: when running into the same issue, i found that placing my generated script in the body worked. It is indeed so that the documentation is not always 100% correct (anymore). But perhaps when you share the script you use to create your plot we could find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If we inspect the html generated by a basic example:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.resources import CDN
from bokeh.embed import file_html

plot = figure()
plot.circle([1,2], [3,4])

html = file_html(plot, CDN, "plot")
print(html)
```

It follows this format:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- generated div -->
    <div class="bk-root">
        <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="7a7b6ca9-3dec-430d-98f2-a0a7067c9ae0"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- generated script  -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {..})
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The **autoloading** script instead replaces the generated `<div>` and `<script>`, and optionally replaces the static css and js references.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- optional -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.9.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- autoloading script -->
    <script
        src="https://demo.bokeh.org/slider/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=aee6d395-d079-4e02-ae72-8e70e617990d&bokeh-app-path=/apps/slider&bokeh-absolute-url=https://demo.bokeh.org/slider"
        id="aee6d395-d079-4e02-ae72-8e70e617990d"
        data-bokeh-model-id=""
        data-bokeh-doc-id=""
    ></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have tried this, putting the script in the body, but I just get a blank webpage.  (I can view my interactive Bokeh plot locally without any issues.)

Comment: I've now tried server_session instead of autoload_server, to no avail.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: For the url maybe try `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html#bokeh.embed.autoload_server

Comment: Looking at the javascript console, there are 2 errors: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403, as well as [bokeh] Failed to connect to Bokeh server Error: Could not open websocket.  Any idea what's causing these?

Comment: It sounds like it can't find the bokeh server which needs to be running as a separate process... maybe make sure access to the port isn't blocked by iptables rules. Are you able to ping or curl against the bokeh server address?

Comment: How do I make sure the port isn't blocked?  What does it mean to "ping" or "curl" against the bokeh server address?

Comment: Again, I can view my app locally without any issues, localhost port 5006.